# Цукерберг, Вайнштайн чи Закерберг, Вінстін?

Tags: переклад, власні-назви, іноземні-імена

прізвище Zuckerberg хоча і має очевидно німецьке коріння, але оскільки стосується американця, то навіть німецькою вимовляється не Цукерберг, а за англійськими правилами, тобто Закерберг. Так само Weinstein, українською всі новини перекладали його як Вайнштайн, але англійські та німецькі говорили винятково про Вінстіна.

Чому українська мова викорустовує німецьку вимову американських (в даному випадку) прізвищ німецького походження навіть там, де німецька мова її не використовує?

Comment: Чи перевіряли ви таку можливість, що українська мова копіює неправильне копіювання з англійської в російську?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMr9QGa0_HE - англійська
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WI0uIRYCCVw - німецька

Answer (score 4):

Для початку хочу затвердити панове ствердження і трохи виправити.

Пан Мірошко надав у коментарях ланки шчодо: [анґлійською](//youtube.com/watch?v=QMr9QGa0_HE), [німецькою](//youtube.com/watch?v=WI0uIRYCCVw). Так, звуки і Вікіпедія вказують на **Закерберґ**

> анґлійською [ˈzʌkərbɜːrɡ](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Zuckerberg)
>   німецькою [ˈzʌkʰɚbɚg](//de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Zuckerberg)

Але ланки шчодо *Weinstein* відсутні і взагалі справи инакші. Я сам знайшов ось такі ланки: [німецькою](//youtube.com/watch?v=ac2qp3QKG98), [анґлійською](//youtube.com/watch?v=Y12mA5oLSgM). Тамтешна вимова та Вікіпедія вказують на **Вайнcтін**

> анґлійською [waɪnstiːn](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_Weinstein)
>   німецькою [ˈvaɪ̯nstiːn](//de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_Weinstein)

---

Так стало, цьому відповідають головні два чинника

- після Московської навали, а саме за Радянські часи — було зґвалтування мови;
- сучасна держава майже ніц не хоче робити абишчо, на додачу маємо нерозвинену новинарну чи поширену писемну культуру, і в той час залежної від Московської.

Бо подібним чином пишуть саме [наші](//be.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA_%D0%A6%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3) [давні](//ky.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA_%D0%A6%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3) [сустрадальці](//kk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA_%D0%A6%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3), а не [инші](//bg.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA_%D0%97%D1%8A%D0%BA%D1%8A%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%80%D0%B3) [вільніші](//mk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3) [народности](//sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA_%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3).

Шчодо Вайстіну ланки важкіше знайти, але за звуками десь так пишуть [латвійці](https://lv.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C4%81rvijs_Vainst%C4%ABns), [ніхонці](//ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8F%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B4%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A4%E3%83%BB%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3). А більшість просто без думок і сліпо слідують [правопису](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par95)

> 2. У власних назвах новішого походження німецький дифтонг **ei** передається через **ай** (**яй**) […]: ***Ай**зенах, Нортг**ай**м; В**ай**зенборн, К**ай**зер, М**ай**нгоф*.

Зазначу, шчо, схоже, не *всі* [новинари](//ukrainian.voanews.com/a/time-person-of-year-2010-12-15-111930014/237372.html) [слідують](//radiosvoboda.org/a/26776169.html) [широкому](//ukrainian.voanews.com/a/vainstin-gvaltuvanya/4065389.html) [загалу](//ua.newwest.media/article/2017/11/13/u-gollivudi-proyshov-marsh-proti-seksualnih-domagan).